# How to transfer data from production cluster to a datalab cluster for real time data analysis?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, mapr

We are using mapr and we want to deploy a new (datalab) cluster, and I'm asking about the best way to transfer data from our production cluster to the datalab cluster ?

We used mirroring, between the two cluster , but with this option we have only-read data in our datalab  , so how could we transfer data in real time ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a FS.a ==> FS.b "real-time" pipe, the best options I know of are either Apache NiFi or StreamSets because there is no coding required.

Flume could potentially be another option because its already available in most Hadoop vendor environments.

You can use Spark or Flink if you are more development oriented.

[DistCP on an Oozie schedule](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_DistCpActionExtension.html) is the fail-safe solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below options:

- Distcp.But there are certain protocols supported in the same.[Refer
  here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html)
- If you are using **hbase**,then you can use **snapshot** feature.[Refer here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots)
- Or,You can use the utility of database to create a dump.For
  example,if you are using mysql,then use `mysqldump -u [username]-p
  [pass][dbname]| gzip > file.sql.gz` and then you can move it to other server `scp username@<ip>:/<source>/file.sql.gz <destination>/`
- Or, you can use **Apache falcon** which uses oozie workflow to replicate
  the data between clusters.You can set one time workflow and execute
  it